# Filter JSON data with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I have a JSON format of the following -

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "name":"example",
      "age":"21"
   },
   "1":{
      "name":"example2",
      "age":"22"
   }
}
```

I want to convert it to the following format with jQuery -

```
   {  
      "name":"example",
      "age":"21"
   },
   {
      "name":"example2",
      "age":"22"
   }
```

removing numbering from keys. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really do not need JQuery for this. You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) function to get an array of values for each property in the object:

```js
const input = {  
   "0":{  
      "name":"example",
      "age":"21"
   },
   "1":{
      "name":"example2",
      "age":"22"
   }
}

const result = Object.values(input)

console.log(result)
```

I assume your desired result is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = JSON.parse("your json");
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);
for(var i=o;i<keys.length;i++){
  console.log(b[keys[i]]);
}
```

Here you go "numbering" removed is over btn Storing parsed objects should be stored in collections, and keys are required to exist in objects. please refer to